# Xcode build system crashing

Tags: xcode, build, cocoapods

Xcode 10.1

- Xcode Product->Build works fine
- Project is OLD. Migrated from pre-Xcode 9.
- No tests in the project
- Add unit test target (containing only the empty sample test)
- Product->Test fails and crashes the build system

It seems to be caused by a link naturally created by the build from the `DerivedData` to the `/tmp` directory.

Xcode compiler output:

```
error: unexpected explicit output: '<TRIGGER: SymLink /Users/bill.shirley/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Projects-aacmhfqthnovqgecjzbjrmjgtxae/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ios1.app /tmp/Kevin.dst/Applications/ios1.app>'
error: unexpected service error: The Xcode build system has crashed. Please close and reopen your workspace.
```

[image]

related but unhelpful [Xcode: invalid symlink error when trying to run app in iOS simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43282975/xcode-invalid-symlink-error-when-trying-to-run-app-in-ios-simulator)

I've attempted lots of quit and restart Xcode (required), deleting of derived data, making clean, deleting simulators, rebooting with everything clean and reading empty test. To no avail.

I would love to rebuild this project from scratch, but it's massive and I don't have *(i.e. want to make)* the time currently.

Workaround 2: no testing.

**Edit: Previously Unstated.**

This app uses Cocoapods.

I tried the suggestion [enter link description here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/24595), using items 2-6, running `pod install` when changes are made (and Podfile update) and it changed to a

```
ld: -bundle_loader can only be used with -bundle
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

invocation is:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.1.sdk -L/Users/bill.shirley/Dev/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/bill.shirley/Dev/ios/Projects/Kevin/../../Pods/CardIO/CardIO -F/Users/bill.shirley/Dev/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/bill.shirley/Dev/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Calendar -F/Users/bill.shirley/Dev/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCore -F/Users/bill.shirley/Dev/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseMessaging -F/Users/bill.shirley/Dev/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities -F/Users/bill.shirley/Dev/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Heartland-iOS-SDK -F/Users/bill.shirley/Dev/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/IGListKit -F/Users/bill.shirley/Dev/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/IOForm -F/Users/bill.shirley/Dev/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/OpenCV -F/Users/bill.shirley/Dev/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Protobuf -F/Users/bill.shirley/Dev/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XMLDictionary -F/Users/bill.shirley/Dev/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb -F/Users/bill.shirley/Dev/ios/Projects/Kevin/../../Pods/Crashlytics/iOS -F/Users/bill.shirley/Dev/ios/Projects/Kevin/../../Pods/Fabric/iOS -F/Users/bill.shirley/Dev/ios/Projects/Kevin/../../Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F/Users/bill.shirley/Dev/ios/Projects/Kevin/../../Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks -F/Users/bill.shirley/Dev/ios/Projects/Kevin/../../Pods/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/bill.shirley/Dev/ios/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Kevin.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ios1Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ios1Tests.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=12.1 -dead_strip -bundle_loader /Users/bill.shirley/Dev/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ios1.app/ios1 -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/bill.shirley/Dev/ios/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Kevin.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ios1Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ios1Tests_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/bill.shirley/Dev/ios/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Kevin.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ios1Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ios1Tests.swiftmodule -lstdc++ -ObjC -lCardIO -lc++ -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AVFoundation -framework Accelerate -framework AudioToolbox -framework Calendar -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreVideo -framework Crashlytics -framework FIRAnalyticsConnector -framework Fabric -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseCore -framework FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework FirebaseMessaging -framework Foundation -framework GoogleAppMeasurement -framework GoogleUtilities -framework Heartland_iOS_SDK -framework IGListKit -framework IOForm -framework MobileCoreServices -framework OpenGLES -framework Protobuf -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework XMLDictionary -framework nanopb -framework opencv2 -framework XCTest -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/bill.shirley/Dev/ios/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Kevin.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ios1Tests.build/ios1Tests.xctest-Simulated.xcent -framework Pods_ios1Tests -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/bill.shirley/Dev/ios/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Kevin.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ios1Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ios1Tests_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/bill.shirley/Dev/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ios1.app/PlugIns/ios1Tests.xctest/ios1Tests

Comment: Can you try a suggestion from this [post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/24595)? In particular, resetting build directory settings to their defaults.

Comment: @pckill I tried the suggestion and it seemed to move the error along to a different link error, and not a build crash. updates edited above

Comment: Ok, now try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19321771/xcode-5-bundle-loader-can-only-be-used-with-bundle-xctest

Comment: @pckill working on a clean workarea, after I move the build to Workspace-relative, I am still receiving old error, but in the new location: `error: unexpected explicit output: '<TRIGGER: SymLink /Users/bill.shirley/Dev/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ios1.app /tmp/Kevin.dst/Applications/ios1.app>'` I can't get back to the bundle loader problem.

Comment: Try to leave build settings as they are by default, do not make them workspace-relative. Also, search for `Kevin.dst` in build settings of the project.

Comment: `Kevin` is the target, Installation Build Products Location is `/tmp/$(PROJECT_NAME).dst` be default