# Xcode doesn't run any simulator due to Invalid symlink

Tags: xcode

I have similar problem as below and i couldn't find a way to fix it, any ideas?

i am using xcode 15 beta, downloaded 17.2 and 17.4 IOS simulators. i couldn't run any simulator or my phone due to invalid symlink error.

[Xcode: invalid symlink error when trying to run app in iOS simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43282975/xcode-invalid-symlink-error-when-trying-to-run-app-in-ios-simulator)

Comment: You could try deleting Project Build Data and indexes, see the answer to [Xcode 14.2 not displaying errors despite troubleshooting steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76421349/20386264) for the steps.

Comment: i tried but it didnt work, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when making a release, references were created in the project.pbxproj file under the ios folder in the project for the build files located under Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E0A1E8EC-60EF-45F3-A6EE-C6DD8E679244/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/*. When those files were deleted because the app wasn't opening on an iPhone 14 Pro Max while it was working on an iPhone 15 Pro Max, the project couldn't find the references again, so no simulator opened. I compared the new project with the old one and deleted .hpp and .ipp files. This fixed the symlink error